# adaptar mi pagina para AMP

Tags: amp

Estoy intentando adaptar un codigo para convertir mi pagina en amp pero no lo consigo, se trata de un ejemplo de internet que consiste en cargar un campo selecion a traves del valor de otro campo. muestro un enlace del ejemplo que vi.

https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/linked_dropdowns/

lo que hace es cargar el segundo select dependiendo del valor de primero, bien lo que quiero es cargar por defecto los dos select si existen las variables de pais o pais y ciudad.

otra cosa que quedria saber si es posible y como se hace, rellenar el segundo select pero acediendo a una base de datos y recuperar solo lo que se necesite en el json.

Comment: Aquí tienes la respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870667/populate-select-box-from-database-using-jquery
Aunque estaría bien saber qué código tienes ya desarrollado, el json que esperas obtener/recibir...

Comment: hola, gracias por tu interes en ayudarme, pero no me sirve quizas me explique mal, necesito usar las funciones de amp para cargar los select y crear un json dinamico con php pero no se muy bien como hacerlo.